# Cold Fusion 8 and 9 on IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, coldfusion

I have a client, who against my better judgement has insisted on doing the following.
They have a single IIS 6 on Win 2003 Server Enterprise.  It currently runs ColdFusion 8.  They want me to install ColdFusion 9 on the server without changing any of the existing sites so that they can develop in CF 9 and upgrade other sites in the future.
Yes, I have begged them to use a Dev server, or run on apache on the same box.

Can this even be done?

Many thanks in advance!

DM

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor? or looked at the vendor site?

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining some kind of crazy configuration with very creative configuration of ISAPI filters, duplicate jrun services, and severe customization of the CF installations to get them to not step on each other.

My feeling is that it can probably be made to work, but would be an incredibly bad idea - especially on a production server, since the process of getting that setup working would be perilous and certain to break things.

This client is in serious need of discovering the wonders of virtualization - stay far, far away from it if they try to do this on their production server.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible. You can install ColdFusion 9 right next to ColdFusion 8, and they will both run without problem in their own JVM space. During the CF9 install, just don't configure any IIS sites. Then, once you have successfully configured CF9, you'll need to run the `wsconfig.exe` application to configure just the sites that you want to run on CF9.

You'll just have to be sure that the server has enough RAM to support both JVMs.

Should they be using a Dev box? Absofreakinlutely, but what they're requested is technically feasible.